How to change timezone in JMeter test run
I would like to know how to change the timezone in JMeter?
The timestamp in my JMeter run is always UTC, which does not align with the timezone of my OS.
My OS timezone is HKT (UTC+8):

JMeter timezone is UTC:

I have updated bin/system.properties to add:
user.timezone=Asia/Hong_Kong 

However, it is still not working unfortunately.

JMeter uses System.currentTimeMillis() function for recording SampleResult timestamp
As per documentation:

Returns:
the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

So this is not something you can configure unless you modify JMeter source code to support this.
The solution would be declaring a Sample Variable in user.properties file and add 8 hours to the current timestamp - it will give you the desired value (however I'm not sure what you're going to do with it afterwards) and it will be written as a separate column in the .jtl results file

Thanks for the reply. Turns out I can just set the time zone with export TZ=Asia/Hong_Kong easily.
